# Deep neural nets: how good do the Boltzmann machines have to be?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning

When stacking Boltzmann machines to generatively pre-train a deep neural net, how accurate do the reconstructions need to be? If they are too accurate, can overfitting be a concern? Or is excessively high accuracy only a red flag when doing discriminative fine-tuning?

Answer (score 1):

What is a concern is not burning in the markov chains enough to suppress high energy areas in training set which are far from the initial values. This is typical using CD (1) or any low order contrastive divergence. That said, these methods will always typically intialise weights far from local optima that non-pre-trained nets would get stuck in.

RBMs are also trained with simulated annealing so are more likely to explore more of the parameter space.

I also recommend you read the paper Understanding deep learning requires rethinking generalization by Zhang et al. It basically shows how these networks practically completely memorise the probabiliy distributions and can still generalise.